# What does "Yeshuos Panai" mean exactly?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, translation, tehilim-psalms

I am a bit confused on the wording of [Tehillim 42](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2642.htm). Verse 6 states:

> :מַה־תִּֽשְׁתּ֬וֹחֲחִ֨י | נַפְשִׁי֘ וַתֶּֽהֱמִ֪י עָ֫לָ֥י הוֹחִ֣ילִי לֵֽ֖אלֹהִים כִּי־ע֥וֹד אוֹדֶ֗נּוּ יְשׁוּע֥וֹת פָּנָֽיו
>
> Why are you downcast, my soul, and why do you stir within me? Hope to God, for I will yet thank Him for the salvations of His presence.

And later the final verse states an almost identical phrase:

> :מַה־תִּֽשְׁתּ֬וֹחֲחִ֨י | נַפְשִׁי֘ וּמַה־תֶּֽהֱמִ֪י עָ֫לָ֥י
> הוֹחִ֣ילִי לֵֽ֖אלֹהִים כִּי־ע֣וֹד אוֹדֶ֑נּוּ יְשׁוּעֹ֥ת פָּ֜נַ֗י
> וֵֽאלֹהָֽי
>
> Why are you downcast, my soul, and why do you stir within me? Hope to God, for I will yet thank Him for the salvations of my countenance and my God.

(Translation from [Chabad.org](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16263/jewish/Chapter-42.htm))

My question is not why the two verses are  nearly identical save the last three words. I read in the [ArtScroll Tehillim](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781578195558.html) why this is so:

> יְשׁוּעֹת פָּנַי - *For the salvations of my coutenance.* [A poetic play on words of v.6 and the first word of v.7.] In v.6, we praised God *for the salvations of His coutanence*, the furthering of His purpose even when they appear to conflict with our own aspirations. Here we proclaim our realization that His purposes are in fact the *salvations of my coutanence* the truest fulfillment of our own aspiration (*R' Hirsch*)

This is not my question. For some reason, the phrase "salvations of my countenance" just doesn't seem to make sense, although for sure that is the literal translation of the words. L'havdil, Christian translations translated the words as "my Savior and my God" but I suspect this is only to push their agenda that Yeshu is God, chas v'shalom.

How should I understand what "salvations of my countenance" to mean? Perhaps it really is just a fancy way of saying savior but Jewish translations are wary to translate it this way because it would look like it was supporting Christian doctrine? All Jewish translations I have seen translate the words the way I mentioned before, "the salvations of my countenance".

Comment: Consider editing which commentaries you checked into the post, so users don't expend their time looking there.

Comment: You understand Yiddish, right? See http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14255&st=&pgnum=160. Does it help answer your question?

Comment: @DanF Not really. It says פאר די הילף וואס וועט קומען צו מיר פון פאר אים וואס ער איז די ליכט פון מיין פנים און איז מיין גאט which means "For the help that comes to me from him, he is the light of my countenance and my G-d."

Answer (score 4):

The *Daat Miqra* commentary gives several ways to understand this phrase in context. One of them (the vocative: "My salvation and my God") is indeed what you say you've read in Christian translations.

On verse 6, it says (my translation):

> ‮ישועות פניו: ישועות באות מאת פניו (של אלהים), והוא משפט בפני עצמו אמור בלשון קריאה בסיום דברי הנחמה<sup>*</sup>. פרוש אחר: אודנו על הישועות הבאות מאת פניו, ועוד אפשר לפרש: עוד אבוא לפניו ואודה לו על ישועותיו. ועל כל פנים ׳פניו׳ רומזת ל׳פני אלהים׳ שבפסוק ג...
>
> ישועות פניו: Salvations (ישועות) come from his presence (of God), and this phrase stands alone, as a vocative, at the conclusion of the words of comfort<sup>*</sup>. Another explanation: "I will thank him for the salvations that come from his presence", and it is also possible to explain: "I will come again before him and thank him for his salvations. In any case, "his presence" (פניו) refers to "God's presence" (פני אלהים) in verse 3...
>
> ‮<sup>*</sup> כן מסתבר לפרש על פי בעלי הטעמים, שעשו הפסק גדול בתבת ׳אודנו׳, וחברו את הדיבור ׳כי עוד אודנו׳ אל הדיבור הקודם לו: הוחילי לאלהים.
>
> <sup>*</sup> And it seems that such is the explanation of the cantillators, who put a large pause on the word "I will thank him" (אודנו), and joined the phrase "I will further thank him" (כי עוד אודנו) to the preceding phrase: "hope to God" (הוחילי לאלהים).

Similarly, on verse 12, the commentary has (my translation):

> ‮ישועת פני ואלהי: בקריאה: אתה הנותן לפני (פנים ממש) ישועות. ואתה הוא אלהי! ׳ישועת פני׳ משמע ישועתי. כדרך המליצה הנוקטת את החלק תמורת הכל, הפנים תמורת האדם כלו. יאפשר שנקט ׳ישועת פני׳ על שם ששמחת הישועה נכרת בפניו של אדם. פרוש אחר: האלהים ההולך לפני להושיעני. ואפשר שכל הדיבור ׳ישועת פני ואלהי׳ נמשך אחר ׳אודנו׳: אודנו על שהוא ישועות פני ואלהי, או: אודנו ואמר לו, כי הוא ישועות פני ואלהי.
>
> ישועת פני ואלהי: in vocative: "you are the one who puts salvations before me ("my face", literally). And you are my God!" The meaning of "the salvations of my countenance" (ישועת פני) is "my salvation". Like the poetic way a part is used to denote the whole, here "face/countenance" means the entire person. And perhaps the phrase "salvations of my countenance" (ישועת פני) was chosen because the joy of salvation is visible on a person's face. Another explanation: "The God that goes before me to save me". And it is possible that the entire phrase "salvations of my countenance and my God" (ישועת פני ואלהי) follow the word "I will thank him" (אודנו): "I will thank him because he is my salvation and my God", or: "I will thank him and say to him that he is my salvation and my God".

Comment: Hmm, if yeshous panai indeed means savior, then what would v.6 be saying then? "Keep your hope in G-d, His savior and my G-d" chas v'shalom? Christian translations overlook the difference altogether and translate both v.6 and the final verse as "my savior."

Comment: @ezra Perhaps "Salvation of/from God!" I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score -1):

An alternative, drush-style translation of "הוחילי לאלהים כי עוד אודנו ישועות פניו" is that *I trust in G-d that we will again acknowledge the turning of (or paying heed of) His countenance.* (to us) And this is accomplished by our returning (*turning*) to G-d.

This follows the meaning of ישע as found in [Bereshit 4:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.4.4?lang=bi) which says:

> וְהֶ֨בֶל הֵבִ֥יא גַם־ה֛וּא מִבְּכֹר֥וֹת צֹאנ֖וֹ וּמֵֽחֶלְבֵהֶ֑ן **וַיִּ֣שַׁע** יְהוָ֔ה אֶל־הֶ֖בֶל וְאֶל־מִנְחָתֽוֹ׃

This follows Rashi's understanding that ישע, from the root שעה is a synonym for ויפן, to turn.

> **וישע** וַיִּפֶן, וְכֵן וְאֶל מִנְחָתוֹ **לֹא שָׁעָה**-לֹא פָנָה, וְכֵן וְלֹא **יִשְׁעֶה** (ישעיהו י"ז)-לֹא יִפְנֶה, וְכֵן **שְׁעֵה** מֵעָלָיו (איוב י"ד) פְּנֵה מֵעָלָיו:

The Targum to Bereshit 4:4 also translates וישע as *desire*. That we become favorable again in G-d's eyes.

The introductory words to this chapter of Tehillim explain that it is intended to arouse the hearts of those Jews who are unable to feel or appreciate the great loss of having been exiled from their Father's table. It tries to inform those individuals of the benefits of G-d's service and promises that G-d will extend His mercies to us from now and forever.

And so, the plural aspect of ישועות implies a dual aspect to this turning. That through our turning below, this precipitates G-d's turning above. **אתערותא דלתתא לאתערותא דלעילא** And this return to G-d brings about salvation. (ישועות from the root ישע meaning to save or to deliver)

And this idea is also expressed in Kedushat Levi to Shemot 15:1 which says:

> והנה **בקריעת ים סוף היה אתערותא דלתתא שישראל הטיבו מעשיהם וגרמו במעשיהם רחמי השם יתברך עליהם מחמת גודל האמונה והבטחון שהיה להם בה' שיעשה להם תשועה** שמשום **הכי עלה בלבם לומר שירה קודם התשועה** כנ"ל. וזה נכון כסאך מאז, מאז ישיר, שעל ידי אז ישיר שמרומז שם גודל בטחונם בה'. משום הכי נאמר אז ישיר, שתיבת אז, פירוש באותו זמן קודם הבקיעה אז עלה בדעתם ובטחו בה' שיאמרו שירה וכיון שהיה להם בטחון ודבקות ואמונה בה' **אין לך אתערותא דלתתא גדול מזה שה' צלם שכמו שהם בטחו בה' שיעשה להם נס כן ה' שהוא צלם עשה עמהם נס.** משום הכי באז, בזה שהיה אתערותא דלתתא. נכון כסאך, שכסא נקראים דברים האלה שכמו שאם אתה סמוך ונשען על איזה דבר אותו דבר שנסמך ונשען עליו נקרא כסא שעל כסאו נסמך ונשען היושב עליו כן כביכול **שאם יש אתערותא דלתתא והמדות שלמטה מעוררים למעלה שהשם יתברך יתנהג במדת טובו ובמדת הרחמים ובמדת החסד עם עמו בית ישראל** אזי נקראים המדות דלתתא כסא. ולכן אמרו (בראשית רבה פב) יעקב חקוק מתחת כסא כבודו, שיעקב אבינו היה מעורר במדותיו ובצדקותיו הטובות להיות שהאל יתנהג עמו במדת החסד ובמדת הרחמים וכיון שבתיבת אז, פירושו שבטחונינו בקריעת ים סוף קודם שנבקע הים היינו מובטחים שיקרע הים ונשיר שירה בתופים וכנ"ל שכל זה פירושו של תיבת אז. וזה הבטחון היה התעוררות מלמטה והכסא למדת שלמעלה שיעשה עמנו האל נס בקריעת ים סוף. **וכיון שהתעוררות דלתתא שעל ידי זה ה' צלנו מתנהג כן עמנו למעלה נקראים התעוררות דלתתא כסא** וכנ"ל. ולזה נכון כסאך מאז, שתיבת אז אשר ביארנו שבטחונינו היה שיעשה נס זה הבטחון היה כסא לנס:

Levi Yitzchok of Berditchov connects the idea of our change in action (turning) below to bringing about G-d's change in action from above. That this is associated with our faithfulness and that it brings about salvation. In the case of the splitting of the Red Sea, this was demonstrated through singing (like saying Tehillim).

And all this is emphasized in the closing posuk of the chapter (כִּי־ע֣וֹד אוֹדֶ֑נּוּ יְשׁוּעֹ֥ת פָּ֜נַ֗י וֵֽאלֹהָֽי) which underlines the *my* turning ***and*** the turning of *my G-d*.

Comment: No no no, Rashi is using the root שעה not ישע. See the next verse ואל קין ואל מנחתו לא שעה not לא ישע. The Yud in Hevel's case is just the prefix for singular male third person. "the turning of" would be something like שעויות not ישועות.

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question. The OP wants an understanding of the (IMO) very literal translation of the words; you give, as you acknowledge, a very loose one. I would imagine this is why your post has a -3.